# Re-base sub-branch off master

Tags: git, git-branch

still wrapping my head around GIT...

I created a branch off another branch by mistake.  Looks like this:

```
                    c1...c2
                   /
            b1...b2...b3
           /
a1...a2...a3...a4
```

Meant to do this:

```
            b1...b2...b3
           /
a1...a2...a3...a4
           \
            c1...c2
```

I assume there's some way to fix this but after some time with the docs etc. I'm not seeing it. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `c2` branch:

```
git rebase --onto a3 b2
```

Comment: Will try it and report back.  Might take a bit as every time I touch GIT I end up spending 6 hours lost in confusion :)

Comment: Thanks @Stuart.  I ended up doing something different, but in my playing tested your solution on a dummy repo and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

lets say your branches are a,b & c , if you created branch **c** from **b** instead of creating it from branch **a**

this is what i would do to fix it

```
git rebase --onto a b c
```